# C#: Display if a percentage is a negative value or not

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, percentage, string.format

Simple one here. I am calculating the percentage difference between two values. I want to display them on a web page. The calculation occurs within my class file, e.g.

```
public decimal UnitPercentageDifference { get { return (decimal)ComparativeTotalSold / (decimal)BaseTotalSold; } }
```

In my View then, I display the value like this:

```
<p><%: String.Format("{0:0.0%}",Model.OverallSummary.UnitPercentageDifference) %> increase/decrease on previous month</p>
```

I want to be able to display a minus ( - ) sign if the value is negative, however this doesn't happen and it just looks like a normal positive percentage.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What values of ComparativeTotalSold and BasetotalSold are you using to get negative values out of this?

Comment: I was wondering the same, he probably means if it's a decrease he wants to show a minus.

Comment: The format seems to work ok:
String.Format("{0:0.0%}", -12.3) -> -1230.0%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this mask {0:0.0%;-0.0%}

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) (see about ; seperator)

EDIT: Did some testing - you should get correct negative output with your existing mask. So check your calculation routines.

Comment: Yup, it was my calculations. Math isn't my strongest point ;-)